# How to achieve Dynamic code Loading in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, dynamic-loading

Objective:

I have an android application (main) from which I want to download (jar, apk, or any sort of package) and load the package dynamically and start the main activity of my loaded package from my main application.

The solutions I have tried:

I have followed this blog post and try to load the app using DexClassLoader [https://medium.com/@kalpeshchandora12/dynamic-code-loading-in-android-dea83ba3bc85#:~:text=DCL(Dynamic%20code%20loading)%20allows,location%20and%20executed%20at%20runtime](https://medium.com/@kalpeshchandora12/dynamic-code-loading-in-android-dea83ba3bc85#:%7E:text=DCL(Dynamic%20code%20loading)%20allows,location%20and%20executed%20at%20runtime). I am able to follow all the step and able to load the class from the downloaded apk, now I don't know how to call the main activity of the loaded apk.

I have followed this plugin(https://github.com/DroidPluginTeam/DroidPlugin), which is telling me that I can dynamically load the apk from the server, and then I can install it in the background and then can run it by any communication method (broadcasting, AIDL, etc.) but while following the plugin, I have encountered an error (sort of I/O error while opening APK), it's not able to open my apk for installation.

I don't know if whatever I tried is correct or not and I am not an android guy, instead, I am a unity guy and trying to run my games (I have almost 50) within android applications. There is no choice of loading the game statically in the android project because it severely increases the size.

Please recommend me an approach to achieve this task or if anyone can guide me on how to solve the problems that I am facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need look at [Feature Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/play-feature-delivery).

Comment: Let me give a more detailed answer to how I made it work. At first, I converted my UnityLibrary in android Library, and then I have converted that library into a feature delivery project and it works for me!